# ¿Cómo leo una matriz de forma ordenada por columnas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, bucles, matrices

La actividad a realizar es la siguiente:

Tengo una matriz

```
v = [[3, 5, 8],[4, 9, 11]]
```

y deseo hacer un `print` de cada elemento de la siguiente forma:

> ```
> 3
> 4
> 5
> 9
> 8
> 11
> ```

La forma de resolverlo se me ocurrió hacerlo así :

```
for i in range (3):
    for j in range(2):
      print (v[j][i])
```

Pero igual siento que está hardcodeado para la solución y no lo estoy interpretando correctamente, ¿hay alguna manera de resolverlo de forma más natural para recordarlo y aplicarlo en casos más generales en diferentes matrices?

Si es posible una respuesta que utilice los `len` como `range` mejor.

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias por tu respuesta FJSevilla

Answer (score 1):

Realmente casi te has respondido, la forma de hacerlo genérico (asumiendo siempre que la lista es una matriz correctamente formada, mismos items por fila), es usar `len`. El número de filas lo conseguimos simplemente aplicándolo sobre la lista, el número de columnas se puede obtener aplicando `len` sobre la primera fila:

```
v=[[3, 5, 8], [4, 9, 11]]

for i in range(len(v[0])):
    for j in range(len(v)):
        print(v[j][i])
```

Pero quizás la forma más apropiada de hacer ésto en Python  es usar `zip` para iterar sobre las columnas directamente:

```
for col in zip(*v):
    for row in col:
        print(row)
```

o en una sola llamada a `print`, usando una expresión generadora:

```
print(*(row for col in zip(*v) for row in col), sep="\n")
```

La clave es `zip(*v)`, por pasos:

- `*v` desempaqueta la lista, es decir, es equivalente a pasarle a la función cada fila de la matriz por separado, en este caso:

  ```
  zip(v[0], v[1])
  ```
- `zip` recibe un número indeterminado de iterables y genera un iterador que en cada iteración retorna una tupla resultado de obtener el iésimo item de cada uno de cada uno de los iterables pasados como argumento. En nuestro caso, equivale a generar las columnas:

  ```
  for columna in zip(*v):
      print(columna)
  ```

  > ```
  > (3, 4)   # (v[0][0], v[1][0])
  > (5, 9)   # (v[0][1], v[1][1])
  > (8, 11)  # (v[0][2], v[1][2])
  > ```

Comment: Otra forma, si tiene instalado `numpy`, sería: `v2 = np.array(v).T` y luego imprimir los elementos de `v2` normalmente con un ciclo.

Comment: Si, de hecho se puede hacer directamente `print(*np.ravel(np.array(v).T), sep="\n")`, aunque estamos creando un array y con suerte  dos vistas solo para imprimir ...